# How to stop kernel_task from constantly using over 400% CPU?

Tags: macos, memory, performance, server.app, cpu

Configuration:

- Model Name: Mac mini (Late 2012)
- Model Identifier: Macmini6,2
- System Version: OS X v10.11.3 (El Capitan)

For the past few weeks, `kernel_task` has been using over 400% CPU and its virtual memory size has ballooned up to 68.97 GB. Even after restarting, `kernel_task` starts hammering the CPU right away. In addition to `kernel_task`, there is also another process high up in *Activity Monitor*’s list that is always running and is constantly using between 90% to 100% of the CPU:

- `Python` (running under the user: `_devicemgr`)

I’ve tried quitting this process, but to no avail… the process just reopens using the same amount of CPU resources.

Comment: If you have a UPS connected via USB to your Mac, disconnect and reconnect the USB cable. I had a similar problem after updating from 10.11.3 to 10.11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/HT203184):

> Activity Monitor may show that a process named kernel_task is using a large percentage of your CPU, and during this time you may notice a lot of fan activity. This process helps manage temperature by making the CPU less available to processes that are using the CPU intensely. In other words, kernel_task responds to conditions that cause your CPU to become too hot. When the temperature decreases, kernel_task automatically reduces its activity.

This would imply that `kernel_task`’s CPU usage will decrease once the process causing the CPU to overheat is stopped. Unfortunately, it was impossible to tell in *Activity Monitor* exactly what started the `Python` process owned by `_devicemgr` to begin with. Thankfully, someone else in this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26276621#26276621) already did the detective work.

The steps I used to solve the problem:

1. Moved *Server.app* to the Trash.
2. Clicked **OK** in the **Server app removal detected.** dialog box: [image: Server app removal detection dialog box]
3. The `Python` process owned by `_devicemgr` finally stopped, and `kernel_task`’s CPU usage dropped dramatically to far more normal levels (3 – 10 %)… making my Mac finally *usable* again!

---

Optionally, *Server.app* can be moved out of the *Trash* and back into the *Applications* folder. I attempted this and reopened it. After starting back up and setting up services, it gave a curious error related to `DeviceManager` (which is quite interesting considering the CPU was being trashed for the past few weeks thanks to a process running under `_devicemgr` in the first place): [image: DeviceManager error]

More details in *Console.app*: [image: Console.app _devicemgr errors]

In any case, clicking on **Continue** and ignoring the error doesn’t seem to have any negative repercussions (*yet*) and CPU usage hasn’t seemed to spike yet either, so I’d say problem solved!